# To rotate a shaft at a smooth constant 3-4rpm

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I have a device with a shaft which I need to rotate at a smooth constant 3-4rpm.

I would like a simple mechanical way to do this say for 24hrs and then reset by maybe physically lift a heavy item to Zero position then start rotating the shaft again.
I would prefer not to have a braking system as this could wear out and as it wears the speed would change.
Can anyone suggest a method ?
Thank you

Comment: is this more complex than gearing it down to the rpm you want?

Answer (score 2):

A rotary damper is likely the device you require to accomplish your objective. The general concept is an enclosure with a shaft to which your shaft is attached. Within the enclosure, some form of impeller/paddle/fan rotates in a fluid.

This fluid can be air, which would require a rather large paddle to accomplish equilibrium.
The fluid can be liquid of varying viscosity, tuned to meet the system requirements. Light oil would provide lower levels of damping compared to high viscosity oil such as hydraulic fluid or gearbox oil.

A fairly old movie, the name of which escapes me, used a paddle fan mounted on an axle with a cable drum. The characters in the movie attached to the cable and jumped from a building. The paddle fan (think riverboat paddle drive) reached a maximum rpm and prevented the jumper from injury due to gravity.

One might combine a high ratio gear reduction with the damper to fine tune the desired rpm.

A search for rotary dampers returned a number of sources, primarily for small loads. For larger load applications, it might be necessary to engineer and build from the ground up or use other devices in a repurposed manner.

For example, a hydraulic pump driven by your shaft would provide resistance, constant self-lubrication and with a valve controlling the flow from reservoir feed to reservoir return, could be tuned for desired rpm.